# Как убрать лишние символы @ из json файла?

Tags: jquery, json, jsrender

Получаю данные из JSON файла более 3к строк и вывожу на страницу через jsrender, но столкнулся с проблемой, в конечных объектах, в начале у свойств, стоит знак "@". Выглядит так:

```
    {
       "@Code": "51.51.3",
       "@Name": "Оптовая торговля сырой нефтью",
       "@IsMain": "true"
    },
```

`{{:Data.Report.OKOGU.@Name}}` Данным кодом вызволяю данные.

Код ошибки:

```
JsRender Error: Syntax error
Compiled template code:

// jsvTmpl
var v,ret=""

+"\n        "
+((v=data.Data@data.Name)!=null?v:"")
+"\n\n\n    ";
return ret;
: "illegal character"
```

Через `{{props}} {{>key}} {{>props}}` выводит ключи вместе c @. Дело в этих @ при компиляции, как обойти это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вопрос решен.

```
    var toStr = JSON.stringify(test);
    var toObj = jQuery.parseJSON(toStr.replace(/"@/g, '"'));
```

Comment: А что если в значение, будет нужная `@`, а у вас убираются все, не зависимо в ключах или в значениях? да и похоже, лучше сразу юзать `JSON.parse` из коробки.

Comment: Решение исключительно для jsrender и обращению у свойству объекта не через `Obj['propetry']`, а через `Obj.property`. В моем файле нет данных которые начинаются на `@`, для емэйлов данное регулярное выражение хорошо подходит.